# How to treat negative values in lm(x~y) function in R?

Tags: r, na, lm

When running my script I get the following error message: `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases` and I'm guessing that is due some negative values?
The script is looping trough a list of csv files and for a small selection of them, the code is working. But for all of them I get the error message. I checked the data and there are some (about 2% of the whole data) negative NDVI values which are always -99999. And I have some soil moisture values which are 0.

I found this solution `na.action=na.exclude` to add in the lm function:

```
model <- lm(NDVI ~ T + Prec + soilM, data = BeforeConf)
model <- lm(NDVI ~ T + Prec + soilM, data = BeforeConf, na.action=na.exclude)
```

But the same error still occurs. Do you have any other solution for this, besides deleting the negative values from the data. Best would be to ignore the whole the not exclude these values in the linear regression (lm) or to ignore the whole csv file. If there are negative values in it.

Comment: The error message says that you have `0 (non-NA) cases`. Check if `T`, `Prec` and `soilM` have values in `BeforeConf`. I guess an *NDVI* of `-99999` indicates that it should be `NA`.

Comment: You need to check your data some more. This is not about negative values (but these *should*  actually be turned into `NA` values if they indicate an NA value). The error message is a clear indication that something is wrong with your data. You should check `str(BeforeConf)` and `summary(BeforeConf)`. Try to produce plots of the DV vs each predictor. I'd bet at least one of these plots will also fail.

Comment: @GKi I'm not sure if -99999 is treated as NA. But `0 (non-NA) cases` means there are no NA values right?

Comment: @Mathias No the opposite. It means that there are only NA cases.

Comment: @Roland The problem with checking the data is, that I'm using the small csv files and not the whole dataset. Some of the files are without -99999 data. So these work. But I can load the full dataset into R and check with `str(BeforeConf)` and `summary(BeforeConf)`. But I checked Prec, T, NDVI, and soilM in excel and there are only these -99999 values for some NDVIs. Should I just replace them? With a 0 or a mean? But that would affect the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing values in R should be coded as `NA`. You could use `replace`,

```
replace(dat, dat == -99999, NA)
#       X1    X2    X3
# 1   1.37  1.30 -0.31
# 2     NA  2.29 -1.78
# 3   0.36 -1.39 -0.17
# 4   0.63 -0.28  1.21
# 5   0.40    NA  1.90
# 6  -0.11  0.64 -0.43
# 7   1.51 -0.28 -0.26
# 8  -0.09 -2.66 -1.76
# 9   2.02 -2.44    NA
# 10 -0.06  1.32 -0.64
```

what actually works directly in the formula without changing the data.

```
lm(X1 ~ X2 + X3, replace(dat, dat == -99999, NA))$coefficients
# (Intercept)          X2          X3 
#  0.61499466  0.06062925  0.25979370
```

If there are more than one missing code, you could do e.g.:

```
replace(dat, array(unlist(dat) %in% c(-99999, -88888), dim(dat)), NA)
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(30), 2), 10, 3))
dat[2, 1] <- -99999
dat[5, 2] <- -99999
dat[9, 3] <- -99999
```